# Trying to access a file

Tags: c#, file

Using C#
I keep getting an error message when trying to access a file that I know exists and I know the file-path is correct. This is the first of a few times I need to access the file and they all fail to locate the file.

FYI, i'm still learning/new to C# so it could be something simple I just don't know.

```
input[2] = query.txt //this is actually from a user input in the program

string docPath = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\";
string datafile = docPath + input[2];

int inputlinecount = System.IO.File.ReadLines(inputfile).Count();
```

The error message that keeps coming up:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Steve\Documents\query.txt'.'

Comment: What if you right click the app and 'run as administrator'?

Comment: @zaitsman I'd assume nothing different, since the file is located in user space.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code if `input[2]` actually does contain a valid file name.

Comment: try to validate first if file exist File.Exists(datafile)

Comment: 1. Use `Path.Combine` instead of just + 2. Check if the file exists with `File.Exists` before accessing. With that it should work unless there are some weird permission issues I'm missing.

Comment: What is the value of inputfile? Can you share that? If possible include all of your code block.

Comment: put try catch block and catch FileNotFoundException and see the addtional data of the caught exception to figure out the exact reason. [Exception Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?view=netframework-4.8#System_Exception_Data) .  
It gets a collection of key/value pairs that provide additional user-defined information about the exception.

Comment: input[2] might have a correct name. does the file exist in the location C:\Users\Steve\Documents\query.txt?

Comment: If your system is hiding file extensions, your actual file name could be query.txt.txt so you might want to check that.

Comment: Thank you @Vlam, turns out I didn't think of the obvious. (if you post an answer i can accept this as being answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is hiding file extensions. So your actual filename could be query.txt.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this code?

this code access a file and read file data

```
string docPath = @"C:\Users\Steve\Documents\";
string datafile = docPath + input[2];

// make a filestream
FileStream fs = new FileStream(datafile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

// read file and print to console
while(!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}

reader.Close();
```